# I need to print an asterisk at the end of each column if the column is never visually changed. Advice?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, multidimensional-array

```
   /**
    * Fills the mutations array and sends to printMutations
    * @param firstString original DNA generation.
    */

   public static void mutation(String firstString)
   {
      final int ROWSINDEX = 26;
      final int SPACEUSED = firstString.length();


      char[][] mutations = new char[ROWSINDEX][SPACEUSED];
      String dnaChars = "AGTC";

      for (int i = 0; i < SPACEUSED; i++)
      {
         mutations[0][i] = firstString.charAt(i);
      }

      for (int i = 1; i < ROWSINDEX - 1; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < SPACEUSED; j++)
         {
            mutations[i][j] = mutations[i - 1][j];

          }
          int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * (SPACEUSED));
          int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * (dnaChars.length()));
          mutations[i][randomIndex] = dnaChars.charAt(randomChar);  
         }
            printMutations(mutations, ROWSINDEX, SPACEUSED);
         }


   /**
    * Prints the 25 generations of mutations and the astrixes.
    * @param mutations array that holds the mutated generations
    * @param ROWSINDEX integer holding the max amount of rows possible
    * @param SPACEUSED integer that holds the number of columns
    */

   public static void printMutations(char[][] mutations, int ROWSINDEX, int SPACEUSED)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < ROWSINDEX; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < SPACEUSED; j++)
         {
            System.out.print(" " +  mutations[i][j]); 
         }

         if (i > 0)
         {
            char[] a = mutations[i];
            char[] a2 = mutations[i - 1];
            if (Arrays.equals( a, a2 ) == true)
            {
               System.out.print("*");
            }
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }
   }
}
```

At the end of the output, you should print an asterisk below the column of any letter that did not change during the course of the simulation.

An example run of the program should appear like this:

```
$ java BeckJ0926
Enter a DNA sequence up to 80 bp: ATTCGGCTA
ATTCGGCTA
ATCCGGCTA
ATCCGTCTA
ATCCGTCTA *
...
ATCCGTCTT
AACCGTCTT
AATCGTCTT
*  ** **
```

I don't know whether it would be best to set up a boolean array to determine whether each column has changed or not, which is what I was originally trying to do.  I cannot use arrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the line

```
mutations[i][randomIndex] = dnaChars.charAt(randomChar);
```

to

```
char currentChar = mutations[i][randomIndex];
if (currentChar == randomChar) {
    System.out.print("*");
} else {
    mutations[i][randomIndex] = dnaChars.charAt(randomChar);
    printMutation(mutations[i]);
}
```

and change the print function to take one mutation and print it.

```
private void printMutation(char[] mutation) {
    for (char a : mutation) {
        System.out.print(a + " ");
    }
}
```

Is that helpful?